# Ng-repeat recurring element cannot be clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I added a click event on an element with ng-repeat

The odd thing is that only clicking on the last element in the ng-repeat loop is valid

***This is the data that comes out***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRBla.jpg)

```
    <div ng-click="as()" ui-sref="purchasing({idx:'1'})"  ng-repeat="item in bookdata | filterpx:order[0].ord:order[0].des | filterByObj:filterObj " class="pldata_book">
 restrict: 'A',
replace: true,
scope:{
    bookdata:'=',
    filterObj:'=',
    order:'=',
    orderlx:'=',
},
templateUrl: 'view/template/pldata.html',
link:function($scope,element,attr){
    $scope.as=function(){
        console.log(7);
    }
}
```

> In the back, I define two filters myself

I just learned that the novice bird wants you to teach me a thing or two. Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you have both ui-sref and ng-click on the same div? Decide: either you want to navigate, or you want to execute some code. If you want to execute some code then navigate, then navigate programmatically at the end of the as() function. That said, if you want help, post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Well, thanks for the problem